# Unix tool : pretty print code

Tags: unix, coding-style, pretty-print

I am in the process of porting a code to different language and running it on different servers etc.

As a step1 : we are just printing out the commands that are run since there are too many env issues to go through for actual env. So currently the output we are producing is :

```
    fn a
    {
    executing blah 
    executing blah 
    executing blah 
    fn b
    {
    executing blah  
    executing blah 
    fn c
    {
    executing blah 
    executing blah 
    }

    }
    }
```

This is a big dump that we want to review by "reading" before we start porting it. I am looking for a simple utility that I can pass or cat a file with code and it will pretty print it for us.

Mostly just the braces is fine as well ..but upto multiple level. So above code should look like:

```
   fn a
    {
    executing blah 
    executing blah 
    executing blah 
      fn b
      {
      executing blah  
      executing blah 
        fn c
        {
        executing blah 
        executing blah 
        }

      }
    }
```

Is something like that avail in unix ?

astyle --style=allman /path/file:

```
   fn a
   {
      executing blah 
      executing blah 
      executing blah 
      fn b
   {
      executing blah  
      executing blah 
      fn c
      {
          executing blah 
          executing blah 
      }

   }
   }
```

Thanks !

Comment: Have you looked at http://astyle.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: Hi @Johnsyweb .. I tried installing that. It is not producing the results I mentioned :(. I think it expects real code. All I have is some test in {{}}{} . I have posted the output for my example but for the actual text its much more not-prettyprint.

Answer (score 3):

`indent` is the tool you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, yeah. That's a better one.

Comment: thnx @ninajalj for the answer. It has too many flags and the ones I tried did not work as I wanted. Can you please give me a command that will format the braces and indent the text in the blocks ?

Comment: @codeObserver I got this command to work: `sed 's/$/;/' incode | indent -st -sob -gnu | sed 's/;$//'`. ... If you can put semicolons into the output dump, it should work without `sed` at both ends.

Answer (score 1):

The usual stand-bys for this sort of thing are `enscript` and `a2ps`.